# Embedding Google Maps & Changing Location every 5 seconds

Tags: android

Im trying to create an app which tracks the ISS. From what I've determined from the internet there aren't any xml based location sites available that allow me to scrape the location from the site and use that location on google maps.

However there are plenty of sites that utilise Javascript applications; they basically do what I want. So is there anyway to take information from a javascript app on a site and use it in your application?

Thanks

Comment: Your question isn't clear -- are you having trouble getting the current location of ISS or are you asking about how you can update an embedded google map with the new location?

Comment: Abit of both actually. If you look at this website http://spaceflight.nasa.gov/realdata/tracking/ it basically does what I want. I just want to take this - data only if possible and place it in my app

Answer (score 0):

In terms of getting the current ISS location, you'll need to find an API that provides that info. But once you get the geocode, you can use GWT Maps to map the location: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-maps-v3/ (you can also use straight JS). Within android you would call the WebView to load a web page with the map.